# Python hangman error

Tags: python

Im making a hangman. here is my code:

```
from random import choice


word = choice(["gpu", "cpu","motherboard","alu","cache","ram","hardware","hosted software","monitor","keyboard"])
word_len = len(word)
guessed = []
wrong = 6
space = word.find(" ")!=-1
while True and wrong > 0:
    out = ""
    if space == True:  #somewords have a space so i did this to 
        guessed =" "   #put the space in there and reduce the length by one
        word_len -=1   # it works fine without this.
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed:
            out = out + letter
        else:
            out = out + "_"
    if out == word:
        print("You guessed", word)
        break
    print("Guess the ", word_len, "letter word:", out)
    guess = input()
    if guess in guessed:
        print("Already guessed", guess)
    elif guess in word:
        print("Yay")
        guessed.append(guess)
    else:
        print("Nope")
        wrong = wrong - 1
        print("You have ", wrong," attempts left.")
        if wrong == 0:
            print ("You lost. The word was ",word)
    print()
```

read the 3 lines of #
the error code I get when i run this is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\codes\hangman.py", line 28, in <module>
    guessed.append(guess)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

as I said it works fine without that code with the # next to it but i need that code. does anyone have any ideas

Comment: You changed the type when you did this... guessed =" "   #put the space in there and reduce the length by one

Comment: Under the condition `if space == True` you reassigned `guessed` variable with a `str` type value that doesn't have method `append` like `list` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You converted `guessed` into a string in this line:

```
guessed =" "   #put the space in there and reduce the length by one
```

Leave it as a list if you wish to append to it.

Comment: Beat me to it! But yeah, that's where your problem lies.